# Anonymous Access to Rest Api query sharepoint online

Tags: ajax, sharepoint-online, office365-restapi

I´m calling lists via AJAX like this:

```
 var url = "https://mysite-public.sharepoint.com"; 

  url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
         },
        success: function (data) {
            completeMenu(data, target);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failureMenu(data, target);
        }
    });
}
```

So in a private site, I can access a list without any problem. The Problem is in a public site with anonymous access, I get the following error:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="es-EN">

You don´t have necessary permissions to do this action or access to recourse
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

I really appreciate the help. Regards

Comment: Did you find a solutions?  Turning off Require Use Remote Interfaces does not enable the _api access.  The list do have read-only access when doing via the UI, but the APIs are still protected.